# JUnit Framework - Selenium Webdriver - Excel Input Output - Apache POI

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, excel

I would like to know, do we use **Apache POI** when interacting with Excel Files for Selenium Webdriver (under JUnit framework) or is there any better approach?

Let me know if further clarity is required.

Thanks,
Saikat

Comment: It may depend on what you need to do with the Excel file.  An alternative would be to convert from Excel to CSV, and then analyze the CSV.

Comment: @user246 Thank you for the reply. My requirement is to read the data from the excel and pass that as arguments to a Selenium function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [this link](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook) should answer all your questions.

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook

Comment: Welcome to the site, Virus. Typically, a single link answer is frowned upon (particularly due to link rot). Perhaps you could take a few moments to apply some of the knowledge in the link directly to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Apache POI for interacting with Excel Files for Selenium WebDriver (under JUnit framework). You can also use TestNG instead of JUnit if anybody wants.

The following things can be done by using Apache POI:

i) Reading data from Excel (both .xls and .xlsx)
ii) Writing data to Excel (both .xls and .xlsx)

You can also use JExcel for reading and writing in Excel. But the limitation is that it doesn't support .xlsx format